# How to remember or store functions (and all the other stuff) in C++ or code in general?

Tags: c++, syntax

I am new to coding and C++ and I am asking myself how to store or structure all these little (sub)functions and code in a proper way?

For example a function to sum up all values of an array or the Fibonacci numbers or all the other little functions and programs which are basic stuff esp. pointers etc.!?
My idea is to create an ordinary .txt sheet and to copy and paste them all there in just one .txt

For me it´s important to have them all at one place. How do you pros handle this or do you guys really have most of this stuff in your local memory (brain). For me it seems impossible to remember all the functions and algorithms or even the syntax (when the code starts to get nasty).

Comment: So you're copy-pasting all the functions from project to project? Write a library then which you can reuse.

Comment: @tkausl I think he is just asking about how to store and remember functions that he wants in his program.

Comment: Main thing is to have a good place to look up the stuff you can't remember. I use https://www.cppreference.com/ a lot.

Comment: @Ramo How you build a function library depends on the tools you are using (e.g. what compiler, what linker, what operating system, what IDE etc.)

Comment: . yes, I want some kind of library for all the functions and programs a "function library" and I'am asking for the best way to do this For example (very beginner):                   Print Number Entered by User                                                                                              int main()
{    
    int number;

    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> number;

    cout << "You entered " << number;    
    return 0;
}

Comment: You will have seen that your compiler normally creates an executable file. To compile and link C/C++ program into a shared library (".dll" in Windows, ".so" in Unixes), use -shared compile option of gcc. The next program you write can depend on that library you just created and access its public methods.

Comment: I'am using mainly Visual 2017 but I would like to change to some "lean" IDE like Visual Code or Atom. Visual 2017 seems to me a little overpowerd for a beginner like me, for that reason. I'am a college student at an universitary in engineering so the system should be adaptable to Matlab or so :-)

Comment: @john Hey, cppreference.com  seems to be great for my purposes. I definitly bookmarked it and it seems very close to that kind of library I was thinking of! thank you for this! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then you are asking where/how we store reusable snippets of code in an easy to access way. There are number of methods to accomplish this, one which you have mentioned is to simply use a text file and copy paste as needed, but in my opinion this is a bit archaic.

I have two main methods I like to use, first if it's code I want to access online or is rather large functions I plan to reuse, I simply make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) of it and leave it there, ready to be accessed as needed. Usually I name it something descriptive so when I look through all my gists, I can find the ones I need quickly.

The second method, and the stuff I do for code that mainly gets reused is to make snippets using my IDE's configuration files. Such snippets usually are written in JSON format and include a trigger word, for example: `for` and then when you hit a special key, typically tab, it will expand the snippet to something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Code goes here...
}
```

And we can simply just hit tab to edit the starting condition, the ending condition, the increment and the variable names. Snippets are very versatile and you can write as many as you want. If you use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) you can take a look at the [C++ tools extension which has some default snippets.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools)

[image: Snippet Example]

Lastly I keep a handy bookmark to a [C++ reference site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) and look up stuff in the STL as needed so I'm not reinventing the wheel or making extra work for myself.

Comment: @ Rietty PERFECT, I didn't know about  gists and JSON but this seems to be the solution I was looking for. good bye archaic .txt library (which was exactly the point why I decided to ask the question) THANK YOU! now back to work but if someone has other methods or ideas, feel free to share:-)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!!!

In C++ you generally put all your functions in a header and cpp file to store all the functions. You then go to the main and pick up a reference to the header file.

```
// A2DD.h
#ifndef A2DD_H
#define A2DD_H

namespace A2DD{
    int GetSum(int x, int y);
}
#endif
```

and the implementation goes in the CPP file:

```
// A2DD.cpp
#include "A2DD.h"
int A2DD::GetSum(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}
```

Then go the main.cpp

```
#include "A2DD.h"

int main(){
    std::cout << GetSum(2, 2) << std::endl;
}
```

As far as remembering the functions, you can simply take a quick look at the header file which declares the functions (no implementation)

Comment: I found another great site which exactly is I was looking for with a lot of examples of little functions and programs: https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples

Comment: You should probably fix your question then. Essentially what you linked to is learning C++, but you phrased your how to store functions. Also I have no idea how his is the answer if you are asking about best practices for storing functions and using them in other files.